# How can I stop my save and print (Microsoft word) macro from overwriting the previous save?

Tags: ms-word

Here's the macro code if it helps.

```
Sub Macro1()

Application.PrintOut FileName:="", Range:=wdPrintAllDocument, Item:= _
    wdPrintDocumentWithMarkup, Copies:=1, Pages:="", PageType:= _
    wdPrintAllPages, Collate:=True, Background:=True, PrintToFile:=False, _
    PrintZoomColumn:=0, PrintZoomRow:=0, PrintZoomPaperWidth:=0, _
    PrintZoomPaperHeight:=0
ChangeFileOpenDirectory "C:\Users\Medical\Documents\LabSlips\"
ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:="Michele H.docx", FileFormat:= _
    wdFormatXMLDocument, LockComments:=False, Password:="", AddToRecentFiles _
    :=True, WritePassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, EmbedTrueTypeFonts _
    :=False, SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData:=False, _
    SaveAsAOCELetter:=False, CompatibilityMode:=14
End Sub
```

Comment: The name is hardcoded in your macro. What should it call the file each time if you don't want it to overwrite?

Comment: I would like it to be called LabSlip. Truthfully, the name isn't important, I just want it so that when the macro is run it doesn't overwrite the previous save(s).